# How to delete LUIS application that was referenced by Dispatch application

Tags: azure-language-understanding

After creating several LUIS applications and a Dispatch application that referenced them, I tried to clean them up again.

When I try to do that through the eu.luis.ai portal, it deletes the Dispatch app but some normal apps do not want to be deleted.

The portal shows a banner saying "BadArgument: The application general is referenced by a Dispatch application. Please, ask the application owner to remove the referenece, your use the flag force=true to force delete the relation."

[image: BadArgument: The application general is referenced by a Dispatch application. Please, ask the application owner to remove the referenece, your use the flag force=true to force delete the relation.]

I tried several times through the portal, this does not work.

I tried on the CLI:

```
luis delete application --appId "MY_APP_ID" --authoringKey "MY_AUTHORING_KEY_FOR_WESTEUROPE" --region "westeurope"
```

and with `--force=true`

```
luis delete application --appId "MY_APP_ID" --authoringKey "MY_AUTHORING_KEY_FOR_WESTEUROPE" --region "westeurope" --force=true
```

which returns `The application general is referenced by a Dispatch application. Please, ask the application owner to remove the referenece, your use the flag force=true to force delete the relation.`

(yes, the spelling mistake is part of the tool or part of the LUIS response)

How can I delete a LUIS application that was previously referenced by a Dispatch application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for using LUIS Dispatch. We already noticed that issue a couple of days ago.

We have a permanent fix in the pipleline (should be released this week). Meanwhile, we mitigated the issue for all currently impacted users.

If you still have the issue, please allow until next week for the fix to propagate.